# add listener vs set listener

Tags: java, android

What is the difference between adding a listener and setting a listener.

e.g.

```
addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

**Answer:**

After aioobe's answer i have tested this in my project. 
So we can do this.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher1);
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher2);
```

but we can't do this.(It will set only the last listener in this case clickListener2)

```
button.setOnClickListener(clickListener1);
button.setOnClickListener(clickListener2);
```

**Another doubt**

I am not able to think any use case in which i need two textWatcher for single editText. Can anybody give such a use case. (should i ask this question as separate question?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have a `set`-method there's usually only one listener. (Personally I prefer to call them "handlers" though).

With `add`-methods you can typically have an arbitrary number of listeners.

Comment: @aioobe so you mean i can set only one clickListener but i can add more than one textWatcher to a single view in my example.

Comment: Yes. That would be my interpretation given the method names. You should read up on the API documentation to be sure.

Comment: @aioobe can you give example for setting only one listener and adding more than one listeners?

Comment: If you use the `set` method, then you set the listener to be the listener you provide as argument (subsequent invocations of the `set` method will override the previously set listener). If you use the `add` method, you can call the method over and over again, and you would add more and more listeners.

Answer (score 1):

aioobe is right, of course. But there is an additional consideration:

According to the JavaBeans standard

- `getX` / `isXyz` and `setXyz` define
  properties (see
  [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html)) but
- `addXyzListener`, `removeXyzListener`
  and `getXyzListeners` are also
  standard naming conventions for Event
  Listeners (see
  [`EventSetDescriptor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/EventSetDescriptor.html))

So `setXyzListener()` is not a valid method name to set a listener according to the JavaBeans standard! Of course you may choose to violate the JavaBeans standard intentionally, but I am trying to keep you from doing it unintentionally :-)

Answer (score 1):

addListener is Java beans standard and setListener is Android standard, both are using in different context. addListner is used only in case of Desktop and web programming because here we have to deal with many components altogether. In Android, setListener is used because here we have one activity. At some of the point, we are using addListiner like addTextWatcher it is because in single activity we have to deal with many EditText.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no good reason for having setXxxListener methods instead of addXxxListener. I'm sure those "set" methods exist simply just due to programmer laziness. It's sad really because supporting a listener list is not much harder than supporting a single listener. It may be true that you normally expect only one interested listener, but there are many good reasons for supporting lists of them anyway.

My favorite example of needing listener lists is to support debugging. You may want to add a diagnostic listener to monitor some activity, but with only setXxxListener methods, the act of debugging can break your code! The bottom line is that when writing an observable class you don't want to make unnecessary assumptions about how it is going to be used.

Here is the boilerplate for some observable class called MyModel:

```
public interface MyModelChangeListener { public void changed(MyModel model); }
private ArrayList<MyModeChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<MyModeChangeListener>();
public void addMyModeChangeListener(MyModeChangeListener tcl) { listeners.add(tcl); }
public void removeMyModeChangeListener(MyModeChangeListener tcl) { listeners.remove(tcl); }
protected void fireMyModeChange() { for(MyModeChangeListener mmcl : listeners) mmcl.changed(this); }
```

Interested parties add listeners as needed, and the MyModel implementation and any sub-classes simply call

```
fireMyModeChange(this) whenever their observable states change.
```

I created [`issue 5711`](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5711) in the Android project issue tracker about this problem. Please star it and perhaps add your own comments there if you agree this should be fixed throughout the Android SDK.