# Android setOnScrollListener on RecyclerView deprecated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

`setOnScrollListener` is deprecated. Reading the docs [from here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener)) it tells to Use `addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener)` and `removeOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener)`.

What is the proper way to `add and remove OnScrollListener`?

Do i need to use `removeOnScrollListner` in `onPause` and set it up again using `addOnScrollListener` in `onResume`??

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener)`
 means you can add more than one listener to a RecyclerView.

`removeOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener)`
means you can remove one of the listeners that attached to a specific RecyclerView. **If `the arg` was set null**, it equals to `clearOnScrollListeners()` method.

And, `clearOnScrollListeners()` let you remove all the listener from a RecyclerView.

Comment: Thank you, but i already understand the concept..  I want to know a proper use case of `add and remove OnScrollListener`

Comment: @rogerthatcode Look at this: [add listener vs set listener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181144/4206925) and [Widgets should support more than one listener for each event type.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5711). I think one callback can handle everything, but more callbacks just let the listeners reusable, just like interface in java. One class can implement more than one interfaces, while each interface is available to any class. Hmm, just what I understand.

Answer (score 1):

**Replace** `setOnScrollListener` with `addOnScrollListener`

and it will work fine